# Logging in to Steam using Scrapy, login and 2FA

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, steam

I would like to log into Steam to try my hand at some data collection but I don't really know how to go about logging in and getting past 2FA. My current code tries to log in and is supposed to save the result of that into an html file so I could see what was achieved. It currently returns a blank html file.

```
import scrapy
def authentication_failed(response):
    pass

class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'loginSpider'
    start_urls = ['https://steamcommunity.com/login/home/?goto=']

    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={'username': 'user', 'password': 'pwd'},
            callback=self.after_login
        )

    def after_login(self, response):
        if authentication_failed(response):
            self.logger.error("Login failed")
            return
        html = open("test.html", "w")
        html.write(response.body.decode("utf-8"))
        html.close()
```

To spare me asking another question, would getting through the Steam Guard 2FA system be as simple as asking the user to type the code in and then sending another FormRequest?

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/developer-tools.html

Comment: PS: Be careful not to use a bot on the Marketplace, is that goes against the [Steam Terms of Service](https://store.steampowered.com/subscriber_agreement/#4).